# How to delete mac apps like "news" "maps" on Macbook Air M2? These files show up with the "locked" option faded out (no access)

Tags: macbook, macbook-air, mac-app-store, locked-files

(1) Looking to delete apps on new macbook air M2 that I don't use. Maps/News/Etc. Please provide clear instructions if you know.
(2) Also some files appear locked (the locked isn't checked, but faded out and inaccessible). How do make the lock/unlock option accessible again.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SU. OS version is important to know for this kind of question. Generally you only need to drag the app to the trash. However, as per [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202235) Apple KB document _" You can't use the Finder to delete apps that are required by your Mac, such as many of the apps installed by macOS"_. None of those take up much space, for example Maps on Mojave is only 12.6MB, Mail 36.6MB, so I wouldn't even bother.

Comment: This is possible on M-series Mac but highly inadvisable. Leave them alone. Next update will only put them all back & you'll have to do it again.